# Jupyter notebook %timeit 1000 times slower than command line, why?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, timeit

I'm trying to time a python 3.6. program from jupyter notebook, but it seems like the magic command `%timeit` adds a lot of extra overhead, giving me wrong stats.

From Jupyter notebook:

```
%timeit a=1
10000000 loops, best of 3: 84.1 ns per loop
```

From cmdline

```
python -m timeit 'a=1'
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0163 usec per loop
```

So in this case the command line `timeit` runs millions of times faster than the jupyter notebook `timeit`. What is the reason for this, and is there a way to fix it so `timeit`from jupyter notebook can give correct measurements?

Comment: 84.1 **nanoseconds** is not 1 million times slower than 0.0163 microseconds. 84.1 nanoseconds is 0.0841 microseconds, so the difference is a factor of 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not reading those numbers correctly. IPython is reporting timings in **nanoseconds** (note the `ns` abbreviation). Python is reporting the timings in **microseconds** (`usec`).

1 microsecond is 1000 nanoseconds; normalising to nanoseconds Python reported 16.3 nanoseconds, so it was only 5 times as fast.

However, I can't reproduce your findings. Using the same Python binary in a virtualenv to both run IPython and directly:

```
venv-3.6 $ bin/ipython
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 18 2017, 14:26:50)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.2.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: %timeit a=1
100000000 loops, best of 3: 11.9 ns per loop

In [2]:
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)? y

venv-3.6 $ bin/python -m timeit 'a=1'
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0121 usec per loop
```

and in a Jupyter notebook, again with the same virtualenv; this essentially drives ipython, so as expected there is no real difference:

```
%timeit a=1
100000000 loops, best of 3: 11.8 ns per loop
```

So thats 11.9 vs 12.1 vs 11.8 nanoseconds; too close to call a difference.

Comment: did you notice one of OPs `timeit`s was 10x as many iterations, would that affect it

Comment: @NickA: the number of iterations won't affect the timings per iteration. It *is* an indication that perhaps a different binary was used.

Comment: @Martijn you are right about the scale, my bad. A factor of 5 is still a lot and I'd like to know what the problem is. The reason that you can't reproduce my findings may be because you are using IPython and not Jupyter notebook. When I use IPython there is hardly no difference in speed.

Comment: @user681814: I just tried it on a Jupyter notebook and still got `100000000 loops, best of 3: 11.8 ns per loop`.

Comment: @user681814: I had used ipython because that's really what jupyter drives anyway.

Comment: @Martijn: We can conclude that on your system IPython and Jupyter have the same benchmarks. On my system they don't and that is the problem, it seems something is slowing Jupyter down, but I'm at a loss on where to find the solution. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my initial question and can close the question here.

Comment: @user681814: you'd need to verify that you have the same Python binary for all your environments; `import sys; print(sys.executable)` should tell you what is being used. If you do have the same binary, try restarting the kernel. I'm also assuming your Jupyter server is running on the same host.